# Importing modules and taking an output

Tags: python, import, module

I have a previously created a module of the form:

```
def function1():
    ....
    return ....
def function2():
    ....
    return ....
def function3():
    ....
    return ....
if __name__ == "__main__":
    do something
```

Now in another file I am importing this using:

```
from file1 import function3
def function4(a, b):
    for n in range(b):
        t = function3()[1]   # getting the second output from the third function
        if ...:
            ....
        else:
            ....
    return ....
print(function4(a,b))  # with some input a and b
```

Now when I run the function in the second file from the command prompt why does this produce the flashing underscore as if there is an infinite loop?

If b = 1, it produces one output as expected, but why does it not work for b > 1?

(Note: function3()[1] will produce a different output each time.)

There is a lack of detail in the functions as this is related to a coursework assignment but having difficulties importing.

Comment: You have a bug somewhere. That's all we can tell from what you've posted.

Comment: You put `__main___` (with three underscores after) instead of `__main__` (with two underscores after).  Not sure if that is your problem but it would mean that that block doesn't execute even when running the module as the main script.

Comment: @BrenBarn: Actually, that would mean that block never executes at all.

Comment: The three underscores was a question typo.

Comment: @user2357112: But if there was a bug surely it wouldn't work for b = 1?

Comment: Bugs don't mean your code explodes horribly in every case. They mean your code does something wrong in at least one case. You did something wrong, somewhere, but we can't tell what. Check the usual newbie problems; are you reusing an object in a case where you thought you were making a copy? Are you trying to modify a global variable without a `global` declaration? Do you understand the scope rules?

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks a lot for the heads up, found the problem, now to fix it.